# How to add switch with handler enable/disable with table row data in material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

How to add another action in the Material table and add this in the react material table with the element. and get row data onChange event. I am currently rendering on the state.

Please check this code and suggest me how to use this.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mb4ecz?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 0):

you can add `actions` attribute in `material-table`:

```
 actions={[
      {
        icon: 'save',
        tooltip: 'Save User',
        onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
      },
      {
        icon: 'delete',
        tooltip: 'Delete User',
        onClick: (event, rowData) => confirm("You want to delete " + rowData.name)
      }
    ]}
```